# Is it possible for me to inject a Where clause into an IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, unit-testing

I have a class that has a method like

```
public IEnumerable<string> ProductsStaleResults()
{
    using(var context = DataContext.FromID(Id))
    {
        return 
        (from change in context.ProductChangeTrackings
         join product in context.Products
         on change.SKU equals product.SKU
         where product.Status == ProductStatus.Active
         from rule in context.ProductDataQualityRules
         where rule.Status == "Active"
         &&
         (
             from result in context.ProductDataQualityResults
             where result.ProductDataQualityRuleID == rule.ProductDataQualityRuleID
                 && result.SKU == change.SKU
             select result.ProductRowVersion
         ).Any(prv => prv == change.RowVersion) == false
         select change.SKU).Distinct();
    }
}
```

There problem is that I need to run an integration test that filters in only certain entities from `context.ProductDataQualityRules`. Ideally, without changing this class itself (possibly extending it though).

So I want to somehow inject a `Func<ProductDataQualityRule, bool> filter` so that

```
from rule in context.ProductDataQualityRules
where rule.Status == "Active"
```

acts like

```
from rule in context.ProductDataQualityRules
where rule.Status == "Active" && filter(rule)
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Do you want to actually filter the data in Entity Framework or just the data returned?

Comment: @DavidG Not the data returned. I need to change the query

Comment: Then you need to pass in the clause to the method as a parameter, and make sure it's an `Expression<>`, not a `Func<>`.

Comment: I don't believe the standard `DataContext` has `FromID()` - if you can change `DataContext`, you can have it return the filtered `IQueryable` for `ProductDataQualityRules`.